# How can i add new panel at run time in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on an asp.net web application where I have predefined panel in my project with
CSS. Now i want to create another panel with same design and CSS at run time at multiple times. I have a button control when i will click that button it will add another panel.

Please help me to add another panel with same criteria.

Comment: I soooo want to answer this.. but don't have time :(

Comment: do you want to add asp:panel ?

Comment: yes i want asp.net panel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is something that you plan on reusing, I'd suggest you utilize a user control for this.  You can them simply add a new instance of the control on your page.

A few things worth looking into:

1. https://web.archive.org/web/20210707024005/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081402-1.aspx
2. http://aspalliance.com/565
3. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c0az2h86.aspx

If you wanted to accomplish this with a postback to the page, add this to your event...

```
//MyControl = Custom User Control
var myControl =  (MyControl) Page.LoadControl("MyControl.ascx"); 
this.ControlContainer.Controls.Add(myControl);
```

Comment: @Joel: I'm thinking so.  Kinda disappointing, but have come to expect it.  At least Alex gave me some credit for half my idea :)

Comment: Thanks For this suggestion. I followed this link http://aspalliance.com/565 but when i am using this in simple page which has no Master Page and CSS design then it's working fine but when i am trying with page which has Master Pagethen its not showing any thing.
Is this bcoz design or due to some thing else.

Comment: I created web user control then calling it's instance in my page.
I am calling through this.

Control newcont = LoadControl("~/PanelControl.ascx");
Controls.Add(newcont);

its working in simple page but not on that page where master and design.

Answer (score 1):

Like RSolberg said, you could write a User Control and add it multiple times:

```
<my:UserControl id="MyControl1" runat="server" />
<my:UserControl id="MyControl2" runat="server" />
<my:UserControl id="MyControl3" runat="server" />
```

Of course, your User Control can be as simple or as complex as you like, thus having repeated functionality on your page.

However, depending on your exact needs you might want to consider something like an ASP.NET Repeater, or ListView, or DataGrid control.  With something like a Repeater, you can bind data to it, and have that data be displayed in a list/grid, that has a common look and feel.  You can give your Repeater a HTML/CSS template for the header, items, and footer sections too to make it look consistent and professional.

```
<asp:Repeater id="MyRepeater" runat="server">
  <HeaderTemplate>
    <h1>Products</h1>
  </HeaderTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <p>
      Product name: <%# Eval("ProductName") %>
    </p>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and in your code just do this:

```
MyRepeater.DataSource = products;
MyRepeater.DataBind();
```

There are many ways of doing what you're asking in ASP.NET - be a bit more specific and we'll be able to give you more specifc help.

Answer (score -1):

Couldn't you just create a new panel in the code behind on the button's "On_Click" event?  That would be my suggestion.  You may need to have a placeholder to add the panel into something so it appears on the page.

Comment: Lots of problems here - what happens after the next postback?  Plus, it doesn't re-use any of the code for the existing panel.

Comment: Depending on how one has this set up, there could just be callbacks using AJAX for a way around the postback question.  There can be other problems sure, but as these become found the answer can be revised to address those as I don't think the requirement was well-thought out here.  The question was about putting in a panel at runtime.  Everything else is speculation.